# Mudblazor Datagrid custom filter

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I'm using the MudDataGrid component: https://dev.mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#default-data-grid

I'm trying to add a custom filter that lets you select from a list of items using checkboxes to filter by that column. It would work exactly the same as what you see here (click button in column header): https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/datagrid/checkbox-filter/

I haven't been able to find any examples of something like this using the MudDataGrid component. The component already provides a "Filter" button on each column, I just cant figure out how to control what pops up when you hit that button. Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: I just checked out the MudBlazor page and there's an Advanced Data Grid further down the page you linked to above that does column filtering.  Note the disclaimer at the top of the page about the DataGrid being under Active development!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yeah, I have seen the documentation. But unfortunately, it doesn't describe a way to accomplish what I'm asking about here. I.E. it doesn't indicate a way to actually change what component pops up when you click the filter button on each column, like if I wanted to change it so that a list of checkbox items pops up instead of their built in filtering component.

Comment: Ask them?  I think your stuck with what is implemented.

Comment: Yeah, I mean obviously it just might not be possible..Just figured there was someone here who probably has a lot more experience with the library than I do.

Comment: From my experience as an answerer, I don't see too many people answering MudBlazor questions.  My conclusion is that not many answerers use MudBlazor.

Comment: I gotcha, thank you for the info. Out of curosity, which component libraries do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but if I understand correctly your needs, look at this sample, they do exactly what you searching for. Open the custom filter for the `Sign` columns. I hope it will helps you.

https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#advanced-filtering